# Efficiently replace values from a column to another column Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, replace, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame like this:

```
   col1 col2 col3
1   0.2  0.3  0.3
2   0.2  0.3  0.3
3     0  0.4  0.4
4     0    0  0.3
5     0    0    0
6   0.1  0.4  0.4
```

I want to replace the `col1` values with the values in the second column (`col2`) only if `col1` values are equal to 0, and after (for the zero values remaining),  do it again but with the third column (`col3`). The Desired Result is the next one:

```
   col1 col2 col3
1   0.2  0.3  0.3
2   0.2  0.3  0.3
3   0.4  0.4  0.4
4   0.3    0  0.3
5     0    0    0
6   0.1  0.4  0.4
```

I did it using the `pd.replace` function, but it seems too slow.. I think must be a faster way to accomplish that.

```
df.col1.replace(0,df.col2,inplace=True)
df.col1.replace(0,df.col3,inplace=True)
```

is there a faster way to do that?, using some other function instead of the `pd.replace` function?

Comment: You could do `df.replace(0, pd.np.nan).bfill(axis=1).fillna(0)` - perhaps not faster.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Using [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is faster.  Using a similar pattern as you used with `replace`:

```
df['col1'] = np.where(df['col1'] == 0, df['col2'], df['col1'])
df['col1'] = np.where(df['col1'] == 0, df['col3'], df['col1'])
```

However, using a nested `np.where` is slightly faster:

```
df['col1'] = np.where(df['col1'] == 0, 
                      np.where(df['col2'] == 0, df['col3'], df['col2']),
                      df['col1'])
```

**Timings**

Using the following setup to produce a larger sample DataFrame and timing functions:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10**4, ignore_index=True)

def root_nested(df):
    df['col1'] = np.where(df['col1'] == 0, np.where(df['col2'] == 0, df['col3'], df['col2']), df['col1'])
    return df

def root_split(df):
    df['col1'] = np.where(df['col1'] == 0, df['col2'], df['col1'])
    df['col1'] = np.where(df['col1'] == 0, df['col3'], df['col1'])
    return df

def pir2(df):
    df['col1'] = df.where(df.ne(0), np.nan).bfill(axis=1).col1.fillna(0)
    return df

def pir2_2(df):
    slc = (df.values != 0).argmax(axis=1)
    return df.values[np.arange(slc.shape[0]), slc]

def andrew(df):
    df.col1[df.col1 == 0] = df.col2
    df.col1[df.col1 == 0] = df.col3
    return df

def pablo(df):
    df['col1'] = df['col1'].replace(0,df['col2'])
    df['col1'] = df['col1'].replace(0,df['col3'])
    return df
```

I get the following timings:

```
%timeit root_nested(df.copy())
100 loops, best of 3: 2.25 ms per loop

%timeit root_split(df.copy())
100 loops, best of 3: 2.62 ms per loop

%timeit pir2(df.copy())
100 loops, best of 3: 6.25 ms per loop

%timeit pir2_2(df.copy())
1 loop, best of 3: 2.4 ms per loop

%timeit andrew(df.copy())
100 loops, best of 3: 8.55 ms per loop
```

I tried timing your method, but it's been running for multiple minutes without completing.  As a comparison, timing your method on just the 6 row example DataFrame (not the much larger one tested above) took 12.8 ms.

Comment: @piRSquared: Added as `pir2_2`.

Comment: Probably the for-loop.  It was the fastest one on the smaller 6 row example DataFrame.

Comment: @piRSquared: That sped it up!

Answer (score 14):

I'm not sure if it's faster, but you're right that you can slice the dataframe to get your desired result.

```
df.col1[df.col1 == 0] = df.col2
df.col1[df.col1 == 0] = df.col3
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0   0.2   0.3   0.3
1   0.2   0.3   0.3
2   0.4   0.4   0.4
3   0.3   0.0   0.3
4   0.0   0.0   0.0
5   0.1   0.4   0.4
```

Alternatively if you want it to be more terse (though I don't know if it's faster) you can combine what you did with what I did.

```
df.col1[df.col1 == 0] = df.col2.replace(0, df.col3)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0   0.2   0.3   0.3
1   0.2   0.3   0.3
2   0.4   0.4   0.4
3   0.3   0.0   0.3
4   0.0   0.0   0.0
5   0.1   0.4   0.4
```

Comment: Using the last version of Pandas the first code gives me the next warning: 
__main__:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Comment: Per [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20627316/5066140), that warning was implemented to alert users in the case when they are using chained assignments, which you are not in this case, so you should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

approach using `pd.DataFrame.where` and `pd.DataFrame.bfill`

```
df['col1'] = df.where(df.ne(0), np.nan).bfill(axis=1).col1.fillna(0)
df
```

[image]

Another approach using `np.argmax`

```
def pir2(df):
    slc = (df.values != 0).argmax(axis=1)
    return df.values[np.arange(slc.shape[0]), slc]
```

I know there is a better way to use `numpy` to slice.  I just can't think of it at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, there are three type of methods to do this conditionally replacement task. They are:

- [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)
- [`pandas.Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) or [`pandas.Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) which is the opposite of `Series.mask`
- [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

---

You can try `pandas.Series.mask`

```py
df['col1'] = df['col1'].mask(df['col1'].eq(0), df['col2'])
df['col1'] = df['col1'].mask(df['col1'].eq(0), df['col3'])
```

```
   col1  col2  col3
1   0.2   0.3   0.3
2   0.2   0.3   0.3
3   0.4   0.4   0.4
4   0.3   0.0   0.3
5   0.0   0.0   0.0
6   0.1   0.4   0.4
```

Or `pandas.Series.where`

```py
df['col1'] = df['col1'].where(df['col1'].ne(0), df['col2'])
df['col1'] = df['col1'].where(df['col1'].ne(0), df['col3'])
```

---

At last, you can try `loc`

```py
df.loc[df['col1'].eq(0), 'col1'] = df['col2']
df.loc[df['col1'].eq(0), 'col1'] = df['col3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use [`combine`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine.html):

```
replace_zeros = lambda x, y: y if x == 0 else x
df['col1'].combine(df['col2'], func=replace_zeros).combine(df['col3'], func=replace_zeros)
```

Output:

```
1    0.2
2    0.2
3    0.4
4    0.3
5    0.0
6    0.1
dtype: float64
```