# Multiple columns with the same name in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

I am creating a `dataframe` from a CSV file. I have gone through the docs, multiple SO posts, links as I have just started Pandas but didn't get it. The CSV file has multiple columns with same names say `a`.

So after forming `dataframe` and when I do `df['a']` which value will it return? It does not return all values.

Also only one of the values will have a string rest will be `None`. How can I get that column?

Comment: Answering this question: `when i do df['a'] which value will it return` - it'll return a DF with __all__ columns named `a`

Comment: @MaxU it was not returning all values...that is why i was surprised!!!!

Comment: I tested it under Pandas 0.19.0 - what version do you use?

Comment: @MaxU same....when i use `like` it works fine

Answer (score 19, accepted):

the relevant parameter is `mangle_dupe_cols`

from the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

> ```
> mangle_dupe_cols : boolean, default True
>     Duplicate columns will be specified as 'X.0'...'X.N', rather than 'X'...'X'
> ```

by default, all of your `'a'` columns get named `'a.0'...'a.N'` as specified above.

if you used `mangle_dupe_cols=False`, importing this `csv` would produce an error.

you can get all of your columns with

```
df.filter(like='a')
```

---

***demonstration***

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = """a, a, a, b, c, d
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), skipinitialspace=True)
df
```

[image]

```
df.filter(like='a')
```

[image]

Comment: thanx a lot!!!! works fine..... also only one can have a value in my case rest will be `NaN`.so how can i pick the only value non nan or nan is all values are nan

Comment: @vks that is a completely unrelated question.  It so happens that question was recently asked.  I'll find it and post here.

Comment: @vks This question and answers can be used to get you what you want.  If it isn't specific enough for you, ask a new question.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/39903090/2336654

Comment: I don't see you actually use the parameter `mangle_dupe_cols`. Why am I the only one confused? :)

Comment: @rjurney you are not the only one. He needs to use it somewhere. By default if it was true then it would've handled the duplicate columns.

Comment: How can I change the column names after importing and preprocessing?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, not due to reading from csv, but I had multiple df columns with the same name (in my case 'id'). I solved it by taking df.columns and resetting the column names using a list.

```
In : df.columns
Out: 
Index(['success', 'created', 'id', 'errors', 'id'], dtype='object')

In : df.columns = ['success', 'created', 'id1', 'errors', 'id2']

In : df.columns
Out: 
Index(['success', 'created', 'id1', 'errors', 'id2'], dtype='object')
```

From here, I was able to call 'id1' or 'id2' to get just the column I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

That's what I usually do with my genes expression dataset, where the same gene name can occur more than once because of a slightly different genetic sequence of the same gene:

1. create a list of the duplicated columns in my dataframe (refers to column names which appear more than once):

```
duplicated_columns_list = []
list_of_all_columns = list(df.columns)
for column in list_of_all_columns:
    if list_of_all_columns.count(column) > 1 and not column in duplicated_columns_list:
        duplicated_columns_list.append(column)
duplicated_columns_list
```

2. Use the function `.index()` that helps me to find the first element that is duplicated on each iteration and underscore it:

```
for column in duplicated_columns_list:
    list_of_all_columns[list_of_all_columns.index(column)] = column + '_1'
    list_of_all_columns[list_of_all_columns.index(column)] = column + '_2'
```

This `for` loop helps me to underscore all of the duplicated columns and now every column has a distinct name.

This specific code is relevant for columns that appear exactly 2 times, but it can be modified for columns that appear even more than 2 times in your dataframe.

3. Finally, rename your columns with the underscored elements:

`df.columns = list_of_all_columns`

That's it, I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to JDenman6 (and related to your question), I had two df columns with the same name (named 'id').
Hence, calling

```
df['id']
```

returns 2 columns.
You can use

```
df.iloc[:,ind]
```

where **ind** corresponds to the index of the column according how they are ordered in the df. You can find the indices using:

```
indices = [i for i,x in enumerate(df.columns) if x == 'id']
```

where you replace 'id' with the name of the column you are searching for.