# Change duplicate columns' names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to change the column name of one set of duplicate columns in the dataframe. I form the dataframe from two different csv files after a bunch of pre-processing.

`merged_df.columns` is this:

```
Index(['PortfolioID', 'FirmID', 'PC_City', 'PC_State', 'PC_Country',
   'Investment_Date', 'Exit_Date', 'Transaction_Comments', 'PC_City', 
   'PC_State', 'PC_Country',
   'fundSize'],
  dtype='object')
```

The first set of `PC_City, PC_State, PC_Country` is for portfolio companies and the next set is for the firms. I tried [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/41466/59059) but made both the sets same. Then I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39986959/4060622) but it can be done only when importing the csv. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas) doesn't talk about duplicates.

Is there any way I can achieve this? **Mods please help with the editing.**

Comment: Adding the second level when you combine two csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding the `firm` on duplicates:

```
duplicates = merged_df.columns.duplicated()

merged_df.columns = [x+'_firm' if i else x for x, i in zip(merged_df.columns, duplicates)]
```

Output:

```
Index(['PortfolioID', 'FirmID', 'PC_City', 'PC_State', 'PC_Country',
       'Investment_Date', 'Exit_Date', 'Transaction_Comments', 'PC_City_firm',
       'PC_State_firm', 'PC_Country_firm', 'fundSize'],
      dtype='object')
```

However, from you naming, you should consider passing `suffixes=('portfolio', 'firm')` into `merge` function that creates `merged_df`.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you want to add `_Firms` to duplicated values of column

Sample:

```
df.columns

Out[372]:
Index(['PortfolioID', 'FirmID', 'PC_City', 'PC_State', 'PC_Country',
       'Investment_Date', 'Exit_Date', 'Transaction_Comments', 'PC_City',
       'PC_State', 'PC_Country', 'fundSize'],
      dtype='object')
```

You may use `where` with `duplicated` as follows:

```
cols = df.columns
df.columns = cols.where(~cols.duplicated(), cols + '_Firms')

print(df.columns)

Out[380]:
Index(['PortfolioID', 'FirmID', 'PC_City', 'PC_State', 'PC_Country',
       'Investment_Date', 'Exit_Date', 'Transaction_Comments', 'PC_City_Firms',
       'PC_State_Firms', 'PC_Country_Firms', 'fundSize'],
      dtype='object')
```