# setting columns in multiindex pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have this pandas df which i imported from a csv:

```
df
0  0 apple  banana  orange                        dates apple  banana  orange
1  1      1       1      1     Friday, January 01, 2021      1       1      1
2  2      1       1      1   Saturday, January 02, 2021      2       2      2
3  3      1       1      1     Sunday, January 03, 2021      3       3      3
4  4      1       1      1     Monday, January 04, 2021      4       4      4
5  5      1       1      1    Tuesday, January 05, 2021      5       5      5
6  6      1       1      1  Wednesday, January 06, 2021      6       6      6
7  7      1       1      1   Thursday, January 07, 2021      7       7      7
8  8      1       4      1     Friday, January 08, 2021      8       8      8
9  9      1       1      1   Saturday, January 09, 2021      9       9      9
```

Is it possible for everything on the left to be grouped under `fresh` and everything on the right of the dates to be under column `spoil` in multiindex format. Such as, there is one column which contains [apple, banana, orange]. I want to do this because later when i set the date as index there would be no confusion as both sides of the column have the same names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['', '', 'fresh', 'fresh', 'fresh', '', 'spoil', 'spoil', 'spoil'],
                                        df.columns])
```

output:

```
         fresh                                              spoil                  
   0   0 apple banana orange                        dates   apple   banana   orange
0  1   1     1      1      1     Friday, January 01, 2021       1        1        1
1  2   2     1      1      1   Saturday, January 02, 2021       2        2        2
2  3   3     1      1      1     Sunday, January 03, 2021       3        3        3
3  4   4     1      1      1     Monday, January 04, 2021       4        4        4
4  5   5     1      1      1    Tuesday, January 05, 2021       5        5        5
5  6   6     1      1      1  Wednesday, January 06, 2021       6        6        6
6  7   7     1      1      1   Thursday, January 07, 2021       7        7        7
7  8   8     1      4      1     Friday, January 08, 2021       8        8        8
8  9   9     1      1      1   Saturday, January 09, 2021       9        9        9
```

*NB. if you want to `set_index('dates')` do it before this operation, this will be easier*

Comment: Thanks for your help. When i try to run i get this error: `ValueError: all arrays must be same length`

Comment: Check the number of columns in your real dataframe. Might be different?

Comment: Could you please also advise how i can get rid of the first 3 '0' columns ? Thanks

Comment: The first one is the index, it will go away if you `reset_index('dates')`. The other two are indeed columns you can remove them with `df.iloc[:, 2:]` or `df.drop('0', axis=1)` (if the zero is a string).

Answer (score 1):

This may help
df.columns.values[1] = "apple1"
df.columns.values[2] = "banana1"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39986959/14310038 refer to this answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
# Get the column number of column `dates`
dates_loc = df.columns.get_loc('dates')

arrays = [['fresh'] * dates_loc + [''] + ['spoil'] * (len(df.columns) - dates_loc -1), df.columns.tolist()]

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays)



  fresh                                                        spoil                  
      0   0 apple banana orange                        dates   apple   banana  orange
0     1   1     1      1      1     Friday, January 01, 2021       1        1        1
1     2   2     1      1      1   Saturday, January 02, 2021       2        2        2
2     3   3     1      1      1     Sunday, January 03, 2021       3        3        3
3     4   4     1      1      1     Monday, January 04, 2021       4        4        4
4     5   5     1      1      1    Tuesday, January 05, 2021       5        5        5
5     6   6     1      1      1  Wednesday, January 06, 2021       6        6        6
6     7   7     1      1      1   Thursday, January 07, 2021       7        7        7
7     8   8     1      4      1     Friday, January 08, 2021       8        8        8
8     9   9     1      1      1   Saturday, January 09, 2021       9        9        9
```