# How to to graph multiple lines using sns.scatterplot

Tags: python, seaborn

I have written a program like so:

```
# Author: Evan Gertis
# Date  : 11/09
# program: Linear Regression
# Resource: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html       
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# Step 1: load the data
grades = pd.read_csv("grades.csv") 
logging.info(grades.head())

# Step 2: plot the data
plot = sns.scatterplot(data=grades, x="Hours", y="GPA")
fig = plot.get_figure()
fig.savefig("out.png")
```

Using the data set

```
Hours,GPA,Hours,GPA,Hours,GPA
11,2.84,9,2.85,25,1.85
5,3.20,5,3.35,6,3.14
22,2.18,14,2.60,9,2.96
23,2.12,18,2.35,20,2.30
20,2.55,6,3.14,14,2.66
20,2.24,9,3.05,19,2.36
10,2.90,24,2.06,21,2.24
19,2.36,25,2.00,7,3.08
15,2.60,12,2.78,11,2.84
18,2.42,6,2.90,20,2.45
```

I would like to plot out all of the relationships at this time I just get one plot:

[image]

Expected:
all relationships plotted

Actual:

[image]

I wrote a basic program and I was expecting all of the relationships to be plotted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The origin of the problem is that the columns names in your file are the same and thus when pandas read the columns adds number to the loaded data frame

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

grades = pd.read_csv("grades.csv") 
print(grades.columns)
>>> Index(['Hours', 'GPA', 'Hours.1', 'GPA.1', 'Hours.2', 'GPA.2'], dtype='object')
```

therefore when you plot the scatter plot you need to give the name of the column names that pandas give

```py
# in case you want all scatter plots in the same figure
plot = sns.scatterplot(data=grades, x="Hours", y="GPA", label='GPA')
sns.scatterplot(data=grades, x='Hours.1', y='GPA.1', ax=plot, label="GPA.1")
sns.scatterplot(data=grades, x='Hours.2', y='GPA.2', ax=plot,  label='GPA.2')
fig = plot.get_figure()
fig.savefig("out.png")
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to label them on a legend? Thank you.

Comment: More information can be found in the related issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39986925/multiple-columns-with-the-same-name-in-pandas), concerning the parameter that achieves this behavior: `mangle_dupe_cols`.

Comment: @EvanGertis I have updated the answer with the parameter label, which is one option to get the lagend

Answer (score 1):

- There are better options than manually creating a plot for each group of columns
- Because the columns in the file have redundant names, `pandas` automatically renames them.

### Imports and DataFrame

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# read the data from the file
df = pd.read_csv('d:/data/gpa.csv')

# display(df)
   Hours   GPA  Hours.1  GPA.1  Hours.2  GPA.2
0     11  2.84        9   2.85       25   1.85
1      5  3.20        5   3.35        6   3.14
2     22  2.18       14   2.60        9   2.96
3     23  2.12       18   2.35       20   2.30
4     20  2.55        6   3.14       14   2.66
5     20  2.24        9   3.05       19   2.36
6     10  2.90       24   2.06       21   2.24
7     19  2.36       25   2.00        7   3.08
8     15  2.60       12   2.78       11   2.84
9     18  2.42        6   2.90       20   2.45
```

### Option 1: Chunk the column names

- This option can be used to plot the data in a loop without manually creating each plot
- Using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/434328/7758804) from [How to iterate over a list in chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/434287/7758804) will create a list of column name groups:

  - `[Index(['Hours', 'GPA'], dtype='object'), Index(['Hours.1', 'GPA.1'], dtype='object'), Index(['Hours.2', 'GPA.2'], dtype='object')]`

```py
# create groups of column names to be plotted together
def chunker(seq, size):
    return [seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size)]


# function call
col_list = chunker(df.columns, 2)

# iterate through each group of column names to plot
for x, y in chunker(df.columns, 2):
    sns.scatterplot(data=df, x=x, y=y, label=y)
```

### Option 2: Fix the data

```py
# filter each group of columns, melt the result into a long form, and get the value
h = df.filter(like='Hours').melt().value
g = df.filter(like='GPA').melt().value

# get the gpa column names
gpa_cols = df.columns[1::2]

# use numpy to create a list of labels with the appropriate length
labels = np.repeat(gpa_cols, len(df))

# otherwise use a list comprehension to create the labels
# labels = [v for x in gpa_cols for v in [x]*len(df)]

# create a new dataframe
dfl = pd.DataFrame({'hours': h, 'gpa': g, 'label': labels})

# save dfl if desired
dfl.to_csv('gpa_long.csv', index=False)

# plot
sns.scatterplot(data=dfl, x='hours', y='gpa', hue='label')
```

#### Plot Result

[image]