# Efficiently replace part of value from one column with value from another column in pandas using regex?

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have a pandas dataframe `df` with dates as strings:

```
Date1        Date2
2017-08-31   1970-01-01 17:35:00
2017-10-31   1970-01-01 15:00:00
2017-11-30   1970-01-01 16:30:00
2017-10-31   1970-01-01 16:00:00
2017-10-31   1970-01-01 16:12:00
```

What I want to do is replace each date part in the `Date2` column with the corresponding date in `Date1` but leave the time untouched, so the output is:

```
Date1        Date2
2017-08-31   2017-08-31 17:35:00
2017-10-31   2017-10-31 15:00:00
2017-11-30   2017-11-30 16:30:00
2017-10-31   2017-10-31 16:00:00
2017-10-31   2017-10-31 16:12:00
```

I have achieved this using pandas `replace` and regex's as such

```
import re
date_reg = re.compile(r"([0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2})")
df['Market Close Time'].replace(to_replace=date_reg, value=df['Date1'], inplace=True)
```

But this method is very slow (>10 minutes) for a dataframe with only 150k rows.

The solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39903090/efficiently-replace-values-from-a-column-to-another-column-pandas-dataframe?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) implements numpy `np.where` which is much faster - how can I use the `np.where` in this example, or is there another more efficient way to perform this operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea is:

```
df['Date3'] =  ['{} {}'.format(a, b.split()[1]) for a, b in zip(df['Date1'], df['Date2'])]
```

Or:

```
df['Date3'] = df['Date1'] + ' ' + df['Date2'].str.split().str[1]
print (df)
        Date1                Date2                Date3
0  2017-08-31  1970-01-01 17:35:00  2017-08-31 17:35:00
1  2017-10-31  1970-01-01 15:00:00  2017-10-31 15:00:00
2  2017-11-30  1970-01-01 16:30:00  2017-11-30 16:30:00
3  2017-10-31  1970-01-01 16:00:00  2017-10-31 16:00:00
4  2017-10-31  1970-01-01 16:12:00  2017-10-31 16:12:00
```

Or:

```
df['Date3'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date1']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['Date2'].str.split().str[1])
print (df)
        Date1                Date2               Date3
0  2017-08-31  1970-01-01 17:35:00 2017-08-31 17:35:00
1  2017-10-31  1970-01-01 15:00:00 2017-10-31 15:00:00
2  2017-11-30  1970-01-01 16:30:00 2017-11-30 16:30:00
3  2017-10-31  1970-01-01 16:00:00 2017-10-31 16:00:00
4  2017-10-31  1970-01-01 16:12:00 2017-10-31 16:12:00
```

**Timings**:

```
In [302]: %timeit df['Date3'] =  ['{} {}'.format(a, b.split()[1]) for a, b in zip(df['Date1'], df['Date2'])]
30.2 ms ± 137 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [303]: %timeit df['Date3'] = df['Date1'] + ' ' + df['Date2'].str.split().str[1]
66.4 ms ± 3.18 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Second method looks nicest, if we're going for interpretibility and "code golf" style. Which method is fastest, do you know? Thank you

Comment: @killerT2333 - Give me some time for timings :)

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to

```
df.Date2 = df.Date1.str[:].values + df.Date2.str[10:].values
```

`df.Date1.str[:].values` will get the `Date1` field as a numpy array and likewise with `Date2` field.

`str[10:]` is done to extract the time part of `Date2` which is appended to the date from `Date1`.

**Timings:** 2.26 ms ± 82.2 µs

```
%timeit df.d2 = df.d1.str[:].values + df.d2.str[10:].values
2.26 ms ± 82.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```