# Replace a string form one column in another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

**Is it possible to replace strings from one column with corresponding strings from another columns in a pandas dataframe using only the `pandas.Series.str` methods?** "No" is an acceptable answer so long as it's accompanied with the pandas version and relevant part of the docs.

Here's an example:

```py
import pandas as pd
# version >= 0.19.2
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'names': ['alice', 'bob', 'catherine', 'slagathor'],
        'hobbies': [
            'alice likes to knit',
            'bob likes to bowl',
            'plays with her cats',
            'slagathor burniates peasants for fun'
        ]
    }
)

def clean(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.Dataframe: ... # do the substitutions

assert all(
    clean(df).hobbies == pd.Series([
        'likes to knit',
        'likes to bowl',
        'plays with her cats',
        'burniates peasants for fun'
    ])
)
```

In this case, I'd like to omit the strings from the `name` column from the `hobbies` column, using something like

```py
df.hobbies.str.replace('(' + df.names + r'\s*)?', '')  # doesn't work
```

So far, I've had to

```py
import re
df['replaced'] = pd.Series(
    re.sub(f'^{df.names[i]} ?', '', df.hobbies[i]) for i in df.index
)
```

as in the answer to [Replace values from one column with another column Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54830040/6571327)

Comment: Worth noting, but not part of this question: solutions that call `re.sub` on concatenated strings need to sanitize those strings.  My actual dataset had strings like `'bob++'` and `'slag]athor'` in them. `re.complie(rf'^{name}\s*')` will fail if you don't escape `r'[\[\](){}+*\\?]'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.replace` is a *Series* method, so it can be applied to each element
of particular **column**, but there is not possible to refer to any **other**
column.

So you have to *import re* and use `re.sub` instead, within a function
applied to each **row** (so that this function can refer to other
columns of the current row).

Your task can be performed in a single instruction:

```
df['replaced'] = df.apply(lambda row: re.sub(
    '^' + row.names + r'\s*', '', row.hobbies), axis=1)
```

This solution runs quicker than to create a *Series* with *for* loop
inside and substitute under a column afterwards, because *apply* takes
care of looping over the DataFrame, so the function applied is responsible
only for generation of a value to be put in the current row.

An important factor concerning execution speed is also that
you avoid location of the current row by index, each time in the loop.

Not also that your code would fail if index was other
than consecutive numbers starting from 0.
Try e.g. to create your DataFrame with `index=np.arange(1, 5)`
parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The apply with replace will do the job here

```
df.apply(lambda x: x['hobbies'].replace(x['names'],''),axis=1)
```

It takes every row of data frame and replace the 'names' in 'hobbies' with empty string