# How to replace values of a column in dataframe with another column conditionally?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
 'price': {0: 639.0, 1: 639.0, 2: 849.0, 3: 849.0, 4: 128.0},
 'special_price': {0: '599',
  1: '599',
  2: '849',
  3: '849',
  4: 'data not available'}})
```

i would like to search the dataframe and replace any value of 'data not available' in `column['special_price']` with the corresponding from the `column['price']`

the result should look like

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
 'price': {0: 639.0, 1: 639.0, 2: 849.0, 3: 849.0, 4: 128.0},
 'special_price': {0: '599',
  1: '599',
  2: '849',
  3: '849',
  4: '128'}})
```

[image]

What is the fastest way to do that

I have tried

```py
def replaceDaWithNil(row):
        if row['special_price'] == 'data not available':
            row['special_price'] = row['price']
        return row

df[['price','special_price']].apply(replaceDaWithNil, axis = 1)
```

This takes a very long time, so im wondering if there is a faster way

Comment: This is not the same as the question referenced, basically i want to replace the value with data from another column, not with a fixed value

Comment: Have you tried using np.where? Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39903090/efficiently-replace-values-from-a-column-to-another-column-pandas-dataframe