# Replace value in pandas dataframe based on where condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace, where-clause

I have created a dataframe called `df` with this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# initialize data of lists.
data = {'Feature1':[1,2,-9999999,4,5],
        'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18,34,]}
 
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
   Feature1  Age
0         1   20
1         2   21
2  -9999999   19
3         4   18
4         5   34
```

Every time there is a value of `-9999999` in column `Feature1` I need to replace it with the correspondent value from column `Age`. so, the output dataframe would look this this:

```
   Feature1  Age
0         1   20
1         2   21
2        19   19
3         4   18
4         5   34
```

Bear in mind that the actual dataframe that I am using has 200K records (the one I have shown above is just an example).

How do I do that in pandas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39903090/efficiently-replace-values-from-a-column-to-another-column-pandas-dataframe

Comment: `df['Feature1'].mask(df['Feature1'].eq(0), df['Age'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where` or `Series.mask`

```py
df['Feature1'] = df['Feature1'].mask(df['Feature1'].eq(-9999999), df['Age'])
# or
df['Feature1'] = np.where(df['Feature1'].eq(-9999999), df['Age'], df['Feature1'])
```