# How to give value to pandas column from other column on condition

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I am cleaning my dataset and just in one column (dtype obj) has NaN that I want to convert / transform with the same values given by other variable (obj).
Do you know how can I transform those NaN without overwriting the non-NaN values.

Here is an example of I would like to do:
in the areas where there is NaN values I want to set the values of region, in this particular case `'NaN' = 'Europe'` and `'NaN' = 'Africa'`

| Region | Area |
| --- | --- |
| USA | NY |
| Europe | Berlin |
| Asia | Beijin |
| Europe | NaN |
| Africa | NaN |

I tried using a for loop: but i guess is wrong

```
Area_type = df['Area']
   def Area_type (x):
    for i in Area_type:
         if i == "NaN":
          i = df['Region']
         else:
             pass
     return Area_type
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: How is the data stored? what is `df`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficiently replace values from a column to another column Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39903090/efficiently-replace-values-from-a-column-to-another-column-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Hi Rick , yes its strored as df.

Comment: I tried both method, replace and np.where, but give some errors. I am going to work a little bit more to get familiar with those functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can instruct pandas to change the value of a column in a subset of records that match a condition by using `loc`:

```
df.loc[df["Area"].isna(), "Area"] = df["Region"]
```

If `NaN` values are strings, use this:

```
df.loc[df["Area"] == "NaN", "Area"] = df["Region"]
```

Comment: Hi, i tried both, and the one that worked was using .isna(). 

Thank you very much, it helped a lot

Comment: You're welcome. I'll appreciate you to select my answer